# Laravel, how to search for product features? get the ids where every item in array is present in table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table with product features
table structure below 
..|product_id | feature_id|created_at 
..|1          |  5        |time_stamp 
..|1          |  6        |time_stamp 
..|2          |  6        |time_stamp 
..|2          |  9        |time_stamp 
.
.
.

how to write query to search with array [5,6] and get result of product id 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like

**product_feature_data** is a model name

```
Proudct::whereHas('product_feature_data',function($q) {
  $q->whereIn('feature_id', [5,6]);
})->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your help,but i have tried this, the problem is that this will return ids 1 and 2. i want ids that have both 5 and 6 feature. (id - 1) @proghasan

Comment: can you more describe with example

Comment: i have a table called product_feature_data which have fields as product_id and feature_id . each product will have more than one feature, and each feature will be added as a new row with product_id and feature_id, so when i do the search i need products that have all the features.(feature_ids in array)

Comment: i update my answer, maybe you want like this